# Initialize extended class through base class factory in Java

Tags: java, oop, factory, extending-classes

It's my first question here so please don't be angry at me if something wrong.

Here is the problem:
We have class Node. It's a base class for class Item. So basically:

```
public class Item extends Node
```

Ok, still everything is fine. But we also have class let's call it NodeFactory that contains static method loadNodeAssets returning Node as a result.

```
 public static Node loadNodeAssets (String path)
```

In the library I am using it is only way to initialize Node class and load assets into it. But the main problem is that I need to get Item class instance but not Node. How could I accomplish it?

```
 Item f = (Item)NodeFacory.loadNodeAssets ("...")
```

Not working since returning class has type Node but not Item.
Basically I need to construct Fish class and initialize inherited fields in the Node class which Fish class extending.
Sorry for my english. Hope for your help. Thank you!

Comment: Well, just because `Item extends Node` it does not mean that all `Nodes` are `Items` (the reverse would be true, though) so you cannot automatically cast a `Node` into an `Item` (it could be any other object that does not resemble an `Item` at all) - Instead, you may need to copy the needed fields (attributes) manually or with the aid of a property-mapping library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should find out what class you are actually getting back:

```
Node n = NodeFacory.loadNodeAssets ("...")
System.out.println(n.getClass());
```

If it turns out to be a `Node` then your only way of getting an `Item` will be to construct it manually:

```
Node n = NodeFacory.loadNodeAssets ("...")
Item i = new Item();
i.setAAA(n.getAAA());
i.setBBB(n.getBBB());
```

If the library doesn't allow you to construct `Item`s at all, then there are only two possibilities:

1. You misunderstand how the library should be used. Maybe you think you need an `Item` but you really only need a `Node`.
2. The library's design is bogus. In this case you should probably look for alternatives, or - if you have the source code - fix it yourself.